# UILabel text error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I am using a UILabel to display my score and my High scores, but when the score label gets into the quadruple digest it says " Score: 10..." but the High score label does not do that.

Here is the init code for the labels (the labels with 1 after it display the text. The label without 1 displays the actual number):

> //SET UP THE SCORE LABEL HERE
>       scoreLabelWidth = 100;
>       scoreLabelPos = 260;
>
> ```
> scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [scoreLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TimesNewRoman" size: 10.0f]];
> [scoreLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(260, scoreLabelPos, scoreLabelWidth, 40)];
> [scoreLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [scoreLabel setTextColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
> [scoreLabel setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
> scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview: scoreLabel];
>
> scoreLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [scoreLabel1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TimesNewRoman" size: 10.0f]];
> [scoreLabel1 setFrame: CGRectMake(262, 230, 100, 40)];
> [scoreLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [scoreLabel1 setTextColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
> [scoreLabel1 setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
> scoreLabel1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview: scoreLabel1];
>
> highScoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [highScoreLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TimesNewRoman" size: 10.0f]];
> [highScoreLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(262, 150, 100, 40)];
> [highScoreLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [highScoreLabel setTextColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
> [highScoreLabel setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
> highScoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview: highScoreLabel];
>
> highScoreLabel1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
> [highScoreLabel1 setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"TimesNewRoman" size: 10.0f]];
> [highScoreLabel1 setFrame: CGRectMake(262, 50, 100, 40)];
> [highScoreLabel1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
> [highScoreLabel1 setTextColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
> [highScoreLabel1 setTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
> highScoreLabel1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview: highScoreLabel1];
> ```

Then in my update section I set the text and string formats for the Labels (let me know if you need that code)

Thank You!

Comment: Please provide the code for updating text too

Comment: make the label wider so it can show the complete number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `lineBreakMode` property of labels you are using. By default it is set to `UILineBreakModeTailTruncation` which results in the behaviour you are seeing.

Alternatively you could set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property to YES to allow the label to reduce the font size automatically. If you do this, it's good practice to also set the `minimumFontSize` property to a reasonable value. E.g.:

```
scoreLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
scoreLabel.minimumFontSize = 6.0f;
```